# vue 3 + electron simple example not working

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I tried to build an example `electron` app, using `vuejs 3`. I am on Debian Buster, running `node` version `v10.15.1`.

I followed more or less the description given in https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder:

```bash
vue --version
3.6.3

vue create frontend
cd frontend/
npm run serve //everything is fine

vue add electron-builder
npx vue-cli-service electron:serve
```

`dist_electron/index.js` was successfully compiled, but after the message `INFO Launching Electron...`, nothing did happen.

Maybe I think that my `electron` installation is broken:

```bash
./node_modules/electron/dist/electron --version
[29769:0426/003034.548566:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /home/info/frontend/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
```

As Cloud Soh Jun Fu suggested, I tried to change permission and ownership:

```
sudo chown root:root chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
```

Now it works as expected, but somehow I do not have a good feeling about it... I mean, I only did some elementary things, for that, I expected to run `electron` out of the box...

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I followed the guide and run `npm run electron:serve` and it works fine. What OS are you using? Try use `ls -al /home/info/frontend/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox` to see the permission of `chrome-sandbox`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the question.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your user. What was the user when you ran `npm install`?

Comment: I think chrome gets installed through `vue add electron-builder`, which I ran as normal user. Also, the directory `/home/info/frontend/node_modules/electron/dist/` suggests, that it was installed as normal user `info`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a recent Electron bug report with this same issue: [#17972](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972).

Downgrading to Electron 4.x is one possible solution.

Another workaround is mentioned, which enables "user namespace sandboxing" instead of the "SUID sandbox":

```
sudo sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

Supposedly this option is enabled on Ubuntu by default, but not on Arch Linux, and apparently also not on your Debian system. To make the change permanent, you can create `/etc/sysctl.d/electron.conf` with the following content:

```
kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone = 1
```